# SharePoint Modern Filter option for list view webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I have some lists and libraries in SharePoint Online and all are already converted in modern experience (new experience).  I want to add these as list view web part in SharePoint Modern page and filter based on URL parameter. Previously in classic mode we have an option to create a view based on query string parameter. In modern I do not get any option like this. Anyone have any idea how I can do it in modern?